# Calendar multiple selection Issue iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nscalendar

Here i am using RSDayFlow Calendar [Code](https://github.com/ruslanskorb/RSDayFlow-Sample)
.I was implemented successfully,but i need to select multiple dates how can implement.I tried to all things to select multiple dates start and end date but i can't able to display.Here my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    RSDFDatePickerView *datePickerView = [[RSDFDatePickerView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    datePickerView.delegate = self;
    datePickerView.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:datePickerView];
}

- (void)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame calendar:(NSCalendar *)calendar startDate:(NSDate *)startDate endDate:(NSDate *)endDate
{

 // here the code What i need to select Start and End dates   


}
// Returns YES if the date should be highlighted or NO if it should not.
- (BOOL)datePickerView:(RSDFDatePickerView *)view shouldHighlightDate:(NSDate *)date
{

    return YES;
}

// Returns YES if the date should be selected or NO if it should not.
- (BOOL)datePickerView:(RSDFDatePickerView *)view shouldSelectDate:(NSDate *)date
{

    return YES;
}

// Prints out the selected date.
- (void)datePickerView:(RSDFDatePickerView *)view didSelectDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [date description]);

}
```

Can you please help it would be a great favour for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this version of RSDayFlow which supports multiple selection mode: https://github.com/aryaxt/RSDayFlow/tree/AG/SelectionMode

Comment: It doesn't support multiple selection. I just tried that